# Call ng-attr-id from Angular in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following code integrated into my html-page:

```
<div ng-controller="MirrorCheckboxController">

  <div ng-repeat="setting in settings">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-attr-id="{{ setting.id }}">
    <label ng-attr-for="{{ setting.id }}"><span class="checkbox"{{setting.name}}</span></label>
  </div>

</div>



<div id="events">

  <input type="checkbox" id="green">
  <label for="green"><span>Sports</span></label> <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="red">
  <label for ="red"><span >University</span></label> <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="yellow">
  <label for= "yellow"><span>Friends</span></label> <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="blue">
  <label for ="blue"><span>Other</span></label> <br/>

</div>
```

This is my Angular Code in an external .js file:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp');


    exampleApp.controller('MirrorCheckboxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.settings = [{
            name: 'Weather Forecast',
            value: '',
            id: 'mirror-1'
        }, {
            name: 'Time',
            value: '',
            id: 'mirror-2'
        }, {
            name: 'Traffic Situation',
            value: '',
            id: 'mirror-3'
        }, {
            name: 'Personal Schedule',
            value: '',
            id: 'mirror-4'
        }];

      }]);

})();
```

I'm looking for a way to hide my "events" div-container if the last checkbox in the Angular-loop with the id: 'mirror-4' is checked. I tried to solve that within my html-file in script-tags with JQuery. The code is working if it's not referring to an ID given by Angular. Why is the following code not working?

```
<script>
    $('#mirror-4').change(function(){
          if($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $('#events').show();
          } else {
            $('#events').hide();
          }
        });
</script>
```

I'm very new to Angular and thankful for every help.

Regards,
Lorenz

Comment: If you're using jquery inside angularjs project, then you're probably doing something wrong. Where's the `ngModel` on the checkbox, and what about the `ngShow` / `ngHide` / `ngIf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use angular you should do it the angular way and try to avoid jQuery. As mentioned in the comment above, try to use the angular logic to approach your request. This is a very basic angular [example](https://jsfiddle.net/6xm5vbsr/1/):

**Add a `ng-model` to your checkbox**:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="toggleEvents" ng-attr-id="{{ setting.id }}">
// If you want to display the "events container" 
// per default add a `ng-init` like this:
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="toggleEvents" ng-init="toggleEvents=true" />
```

**use `ng-if` to handle hide/show:**

```
<div ng-if="toggleEvents">  
    This is your Eventbox
</div>
```

Or to get a bit closer to your given code, you could do something like this:

```
exampleApp.controller('MirrorCheckboxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // we use this to collect the checked checkboxes
    $scope.checkedElements = {};

    // your settings
    $scope.settings = [{
      name: 'Weather Forecast',
      value: '',
      id: 'mirror-1'
    }, {
      name: 'Time',
      value: '',
      id: 'mirror-2'
    }, {
      name: 'Traffic Situation',
      value: '',
      id: 'mirror-3'
    }, {
      name: 'Personal Schedule',
      value: '',
      id: 'mirror-4'
    }];

    // the method to display or hide the event container
    $scope.showEvents = function(obj) {
      return (!obj['mirror-4']);
    }
});
```

And inside your html:

```
<div ng-controller="MirrorCheckboxController">
   <p ng-repeat="setting in settings">
       <label class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" 
             ng-id="{{setting.id}}" 
             ng-model="checkedElements[setting.id]" />
           {{setting.name}}
       </label>
   </p>
   <div ng-show="showEvents(checkedElements)">
    <!-- your event container -->
    This is shown per default, hide if checkox with id "mirror-4" is checked
   </div>
</div>
```

And the fiddle for this [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/cq7q64xv/1/).

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!